# QuerySyntaxException yet Entity is Mapped

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Trying to do a simple select from Java service layer here is my Model:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Entity
@Table(name="PROF_INFO")
public class ProfileInfo {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProfileInfoPK profileInfoPK;

    @Column(name="RATING",  nullable = true  )
    private Integer rating;


    @Column(name="VIEW_DATE",  nullable = false  )
    private java.util.Date viewDate;


    @Column(name="CONTACT_DATE",  nullable = true  )
    private java.util.Date contactDate;


    @Column(name="REPORTED_DATE",  nullable = true  )
    private java.util.Date reportedDate;


    @Column(name="REPORTED_TYPE",  nullable = true  )
    private Integer reportedType;


    @Column(name="REPORTED_COMMENT",  nullable = true  )
    private String reportedComment;

    public Integer getRating(){
        return this.rating;
    }
    public void setRating(Integer rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public java.util.Date getViewDate(){
        return this.viewDate;
    }
    public void setViewDate(java.util.Date viewDate){
        this.viewDate = viewDate;
    }

    public java.util.Date getContactDate(){
        return this.contactDate;
    }
    public void setContactDate(java.util.Date contactDate){
        this.contactDate = contactDate;
    }

    public java.util.Date getReportedDate(){
        return this.reportedDate;
    }
    public void setReportedDate(java.util.Date reportedDate){
        this.reportedDate = reportedDate;
    }

    public Integer getReportedType(){
        return this.reportedType;
    }
    public void setReportedType(Integer reportedType){
        this.reportedType = reportedType;
    }

    public String getReportedComment(){
        return this.reportedComment;
    }
    public void setReportedComment(String reportedComment){
        this.reportedComment = reportedComment;
    }


    @Embeddable
    public static class ProfileInfoPK implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        @Column(name="PST_USER_ID",  nullable = false  )
        private Integer pstUserId;


        @Column(name="FILE_NAME",  nullable = false  )
        private String fileName;


        public Integer getPstUserId() {
            return pstUserId;
        }


        public void setPstUserId(Integer pstUserId) {
            this.pstUserId = pstUserId;
        }


        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }


        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }


        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result
                    + ((fileName == null) ? 0 : fileName.hashCode());
            result = prime * result
                    + ((pstUserId == null) ? 0 : pstUserId.hashCode());
            return result;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            ProfileInfoPK other = (ProfileInfoPK) obj;
            if (fileName == null) {
                if (other.fileName != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!fileName.equals(other.fileName))
                return false;
            if (pstUserId == null) {
                if (other.pstUserId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!pstUserId.equals(other.pstUserId))
                return false;
            return true;
        }



 }


    public ProfileInfoPK getProfileInfoPK() {
        return profileInfoPK;
    }
    public void setProfileInfoPK(ProfileInfoPK profileInfoPK) {
        this.profileInfoPK = profileInfoPK;
    }

}
```

Here is my DAOImpl:

```
public List<ProfileInfo> getByEntityandFileName(String entityId,
        String fileName)throws NoSuchProfileInfoException , SystemException{
            Query query = null;
            List<ProfileInfo> results = null;
            try{
                query = sessionFactory.
                getCurrentSession().
                createQuery("from ProfileInfo where PST_USER_ID = :PST_USER_ID"); //AND FILE_NAME IN (:FILE_NAME)");
                query.setParameter("PST_USER_ID", entityId);
                //query.setParameterList("FILE_NAME", fileName.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
             }catch(Exception ex){
                       throw new SystemException(ex);
                   }
            if (query != null) {
                results = query.list();
            }else{
                throw new SystemException("Query Null");
            }

            if (null != results && !results.isEmpty()) {
                return results;
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchProfileInfoException("No Results Returned");
            }
}
```

}

The db has the PK index on PST_USER_ID,FILE_NAME 
[image]

and a desc

```
    desc PROF_INFO
Name             Null     Type           
---------------- -------- -------------- 
PST_USER_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
FILE_NAME        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)   
RATING                    NUMBER(38)     
VIEW_DATE        NOT NULL DATE           
CONTACT_DATE              DATE           
REPORTED_DATE             DATE           
REPORTED_TYPE             NUMBER         
REPORTED_COMMENT          VARCHAR2(1000)
```

All seems straight forward enough however when I try and query back I receive the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ProfileInfo is not mapped [from ProfileInfo where PST_USER_ID = :PST_USER_ID]
```

Not sure what the culprit is but something has gone up the left. Anything look out of place to you guys and girls?

Comment: Can you post you Hibernate configuration file? Do you have mapping details ? Can you try with out parameter  createQuery("from ProfileInfo");

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed pur SQL with HQL. It should be

```
createQuery("from ProfileInfo where profileInfoPK.pstUserId = :PST_USER_ID");
```

check the **profileInfoPK.pstUserId** part.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I still get the following:


QuerySyntaxException: ProfileInfo is not mapped [from ProfileInfo where profileInfoPK.pstUserId = :PST_USER_ID]

Comment: please post your hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 0):

In HQLs, you can not refer to the table name or its column names. Instead you have to use the mapped class and its properties.

You could check following things:

Can you check Hibernate configuration file for class mapping details ?

Can you could test without parameter then with parameter?

```
 createQuery("from ProfileInfo " );

 createQuery("from ProfileInfo pfi where pfi.profileInfoPK.pstUserId  = :pstUserID");
```